# Should getExternalCacheDir() be called outside Main Thread?

Tags: java, android, android-anr-dialog, disk-io

I am having a call to `getExternalCacheDir()` function on my Android App, and this is causing an ANR for some of Android 10 users having the following devices (HUAWEI P30 lite, Galaxy A40, Xperia XZ3).

I am having the following stack trace for my ANR

```
The "main" (tid=1) thread is performing disk I/O.
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x72dfcb58 self=0x73e23a5000
  | sysTid=12158 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73e3913ee8
  | state=D schedstat=( 378582885 304333911 539 ) utm=23 stm=14 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc28de000-0x7fc28e0000 stackSize=8192KB
  | held mutexes=
  at libcore.io.Linux.access (Native method)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:73)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access (BlockGuardOs.java:71)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:73)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access (ActivityThread.java:7816)
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess (UnixFileSystem.java:281)
  at java.io.File.exists (File.java:815)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureExternalDirsExistOrFilter (ContextImpl.java:2838)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalCacheDirs (ContextImpl.java:787)
- locked <0x0614cac6> (a java.lang.Object)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalCacheDir (ContextImpl.java:779)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalCacheDir (ContextWrapper.java:289)
  at com.mypackage.util.file.FileManager.initialize (FileManager.java:51)
```

When I read the developer reference, I don't see any notice that say that we need to make the call outside the main thread: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalCacheDir()

Should I make the call on a different thread? What's the simplest way to fix that ANR?

Comment: I am, have same issue, on startup application on "install" FileProvider. Here is a similar problem https://blog.krybot.com/a?ID=00950-e3afa93e-daac-44cb-a307-f7e22fa6607c